# Filter issues on Github that will be closed by a pull request?

Tags: git, github

I have a repository with a few open issues. In a commit you can reference an issue will be closed, and these are noted in GitHub that they will be closed when a pull request is complete.

Once these are checked in, I'd like to be able to ignore them while looking for new bugs to address.

For clarification, there are four types of issues I'm looking at:

1. Issues which are closed (these are easy to identify)
2. Issues which are open (still easy to identify)
3. Issues which are open but *will be closed at some point in the future by a pull request*.
4. Issues which are open but *have no pull request that will close then*.

Is there a way to filter out issues on Github that will be closed by a future pull request (i.e those of type 3 and 4)?

Comment: Why not filter among open issues only?

Comment: I've added some extra details to clarify why just open issues won't work.

Comment: I am surprised that GitHub does not offer this filter right out of the box! It is very hard to find and solve unresolved issues when the "open" issue list is also populated with resolved-but-not-yet-merged-into-master issues.

I have looked quite deeply into the available filters and have found nothing that could do what is being asked (not saying it is not possible, I just haven't found it!).

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot do this presently on Github.